# What is the Indexed Code Book Mode?

Tags: reference-request, modes-of-operation

While reading specsheets for NXP processors (example mention in [this PDF](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN12882.pdf)) the other day I saw the mention of the Indexed Code Book mode (ICB) for their AES acceleration hardware - the only mode they claim side-channel resistance for.

However, my search attempts have failed me and I could not identify a definition of this mode.

So, **how is Indexed Code Book Mode defined?**

I also found a related (?) LRICB mode if that helps in [this PDF](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN12304.pdf).

Comment: So far I have found [this](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN12278.pdf#page=17) which is clear about the aim, if not the how: "ICB is a form of CTR cipher mode, but its purpose is to be Side Channel Analysis resistant. It uses a method which is a counter-measure to various Side Channel attacks such as SPA/DPA/DPX (power analysis) and emanation analysis. ICB is slower than normal AES ECB and CTR mode, as a consequence of being SCA resistant. This mode can be used for extra-secure on-chip storage for sensitive information."

Comment: Addition: your guess is as good as mine about if ICB is [LRICB as described in the later reference](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN12304.pdf), or that with some step taken out or simplified.